# Correspondence of French "exercice" and English "year/period" in a specialized, economic sense

Tags: terminology, translation, french, false-friends

In French, we use the term [*exercice*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/exercice/32092?q=exercice#32016) to refer to a period of time between two events. We say *exercice fiscal* for fiscal year, *exercice comptable* for accounting period, etc. One of the senses given by the online monolingual Larousse French dictionary for this word is:

> Période comprise entre deux inventaires comptables, entre deux budgets. (En France, l’exercice comptable, qui sépare deux bilans, est égal à douze mois, sans qu’il y ait obligation de le faire correspondre à l’année civile.)

So it means the entire period spanning two accounting inventories or two budgets. (The parenthesized portion merely explains how in France, the twelve-month accounting year need not correspond to the calendar year.)

Can you use the same term *exercise* with this same meaning in English as well?

Or should you solely use words like *year* and *period* to refer to this?

Comment: Look up the English word "exercise".  If you use "exercice" it will be read as a misspelling of "exercise".  Confusion will result.

Comment: Look in an English dictionary and see if your usage of *exercise* is there.  I have never heard of "fiscal exercise" or "accounting exercise" meaning a period of time.  But don't believe me, believe your dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As the other commenters have noted, one of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate some initial research attempts; there are zero overlapping definitions of *exercise* in common usage that would permit its use as you describe. *Period* or *term* would be the most common equivalent, e.g. *reporting period*, *academic term*.

Comment: Interestingly, Spanish also has this same ‘economic’ sense for their cognate of this word, and one of the examples given for it is even [*ejercicio fiscal*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ESTMxfN), just like yours. But I have been unable to trace when this sense for it entered either French or Spanish. Perhaps this specialized sense occurred later than when Middle English first imported the noun from French during the 14th century, but it is curious that it exists in both French and Spanish yet not — as far as I can see — in English. Maybe Spanish borrowed the new sense at some point.

Comment: So, it means that EN 'exercise' and FR 'exercice' or ES 'ejercicio' are so-called *deceptive cognates* (or 'false friends') as I rightly suspected.
QED
Thank you.